# Square of dominos with equal side sum?

Tags: graph-theory, puzzle

This is an assignment my sister in primary school got. I think they're supposed to solve it via trial and error, but I was wondering if there's a clever way to solve it.

Lay the tiles of a double-six domino set in a a square shape such that adjacent tiles touch with matching values, and that the sum of the values on each side of the square is the same. **The target shape:**

[image: the target shape]

**A double-six domino set, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominoes#/media/File:Dominomatrix.svg:**

[image: doublesixset]

Comment: A few things I notice before beginning: the ability to create such a chain of dominoes that extends around the perimeter of the square *ignoring the summation requirement* is guaranteed by considering it as an Eulerian cycle on the complete graph on vertices $0,1,\dots,6$ with loops.  The next thing to notice is that the total sum of all pips is a multiple of four, and the sum of all four edges is a multiple of four.  That implies that the sum of the numbers appearing in the corners should also be a multiple of four.

Comment: @JMoravitz Why should the sum of all four edges be a multiple of four? Aren't you counting the corners twice? If it was not clear from the question, "the sum of an edge" includes half of the corner tile.

Comment: I tried to solve this as a system of equations using linear algebra. I don't think its working because I'm unable to figure out how to incorporate the information about the pairs of numbers on each domino into the equations. My matrix does not have an inverse, and I cannot solve the equations without it. Probably best to solve with a computer algorithm rather than this approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely not the "clever" solution you had sought, but it does work for a similar problem given to my son as a 2nd-3rd grade problem. His problem was not exactly the same, although in the same flavor.

In this problem, 4 dominos were to be placed to form a square (see Table). Each side of the square had 3 numbers, and the sum of the sides were to be equal. The dominos were (5,3), (3,6), (2,5), and (4,2). The first domino was placed in the upper left corner of the square as shown below. The problem asked how to place the remaining dominos.

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | domin(3) | domino(3) |
| 3 |  | domino(2) |
| domino(1) | domino(1) | domino(2) |

We solved this by writing a computer program in Python, shown below. This was the solution.

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 |  | 5 |
| 3 | 6 | 2 |

```
import numpy as np


def flipDominos(dominos, flipOption):
    '''This function flips the dominos'''
    flippedDominos = np.array(dominos, copy=True)
    if flipOption[0]:
        flippedDominos[0, 0] = dominos[0, 1]
        flippedDominos[0, 1] = dominos[0, 0]
    if flipOption[1]:
        flippedDominos[1, 0] = dominos[1, 1]
        flippedDominos[1, 1] = dominos[1, 0]
    if flipOption[2]:
        flippedDominos[2, 0] = dominos[2, 1]
        flippedDominos[2, 1] = dominos[2, 0]
    return flippedDominos


# these are the dominos we can place
dominos = np.array([[2, 4], [3, 6], [5, 2]], np.int32)

# this is the order we can place them
orderOptions = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                         [1, 3, 2],
                         [2, 1, 3],
                         [2, 3, 1],
                         [3, 1, 2],
                         [3, 2, 1]], np.int32)
orderOptions += -1  # 0-index means we need to subtract 1

# ways we can flip the dominos
flipOptions = np.array([[True, True, True],
                        [True, True, False],
                        [True, False, True],
                        [True, False, False],
                        [False, False, False],
                        [False, False, True],
                        [False, True, False],
                        [False, True, True]], bool)

# an array for all the dominos
# columns are for 8 numbers from dominos, 4 sides to add, and a bool to indicate a possible solution
dominoCombination = np.zeros((len(orderOptions) * len(flipOptions), 8 + 4 + 1), np.int32)

# first domino
dominoCombination[:, 0] = 5
dominoCombination[:, 1] = 3

# place other dominos
rowId = 0
for orderOption in orderOptions:
    for flipOption in flipOptions:
        flippedDominos = flipDominos(dominos, flipOption)
        dominoCombination[rowId, 2] = flippedDominos[orderOption[0], 0]
        dominoCombination[rowId, 3] = flippedDominos[orderOption[0], 1]
        dominoCombination[rowId, 4] = flippedDominos[orderOption[1], 0]
        dominoCombination[rowId, 5] = flippedDominos[orderOption[1], 1]
        dominoCombination[rowId, 6] = flippedDominos[orderOption[2], 0]
        dominoCombination[rowId, 7] = flippedDominos[orderOption[2], 1]
        rowId += 1

# sum sides
dominoCombination[:, 8] = dominoCombination[:, 0] + dominoCombination[:, 1] + dominoCombination[:, 2]
dominoCombination[:, 9] = dominoCombination[:, 2] + dominoCombination[:, 3] + dominoCombination[:, 4]
dominoCombination[:, 10] = dominoCombination[:, 4] + dominoCombination[:, 5] + dominoCombination[:, 6]
dominoCombination[:, 11] = dominoCombination[:, 6] + dominoCombination[:, 7] + dominoCombination[:, 0]

# are sum sides the same?
i = 0
for row in dominoCombination:
    if ( dominoCombination[i, 8] == dominoCombination[i, 9]
        and dominoCombination[i, 8] == dominoCombination[i, 11]
        and dominoCombination[i, 8] == dominoCombination[i, 10]):
        dominoCombination[i, 12] = 1
    i += 1
print dominoCombination
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).